# Troubleshooting a custom "Typed Property" pattern that overwrites property data on subsequent class instantiations

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to put together a utility that works kind of like Python's `dataclass` but gives me some additional things I can do like type checking on assignment, etc.  I'm basically following the general pattern described in "9.21 Avoiding Repetitive Property Methods" from the [O'Reilly Python Cookbook, 3rd Edition](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/)

I'm running into an issue where subsequent instantiations of `MyClass` overwrite data from other instances of it. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
def typed_property(name, default=None):
    varname = "_" + name

    @property
    def prop(self):
        if not hasattr(self, varname):
            setattr(self, varname, default)
        return getattr(self, varname)

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        setattr(self, varname, value)

    return prop

class MyClass(object):
    data = typed_property("data", default={})
```

If I run this using something like this:

```
obj1 = MyClass()
obj1.data["test"] = set()
obj1.data["test"].add(1)
print(">>> initial")
print("(1) id(obj1) =", id(obj1))
print("(2) obj1.data =", obj1.data)

print(">>> create obj2")
obj2 = MyClass()
obj2.data["test"] = set()

print("(3) obj1.data =", obj1.data) 
print("(4) obj2.data =", obj2.data)

print(">>> ID's:")
print("(5) id(obj1) =", id(obj1))
print("(6) id(obj2) =", id(obj2))
print("(7) id(obj1.data) =", id(obj1.data))
print("(8) id(obj2.data) =", id(obj2.data))
```

I get this output:

```
>>> initial
(1) id(obj1) = 4429860720
(2) obj1.data = {'test': {1}}
>>> create obj2
(3) obj1.data = {'test': set()}
(4) obj2.data = {'test': set()}
>>> ID's:
(5) id(obj1) = 4429860720
(6) id(obj2) = 4428300544
(7) id(obj1.data) = 4430915136
(8) id(obj2.data) = 4430915136
```

which is incorrect. In this case, when I created obj2, the `obj1.data` entry is lost. I would want the output in lines (2) and (3) to match but instead (3) and (4) are now the same. I can see down in (7) and (8) that the property is referencing the same location from both classes so I can see that the creation of `obj2` is stomping on `obj1`.

I *think* I know what's going on but I wanted to confirm. I think the problem is in the assignment of the `default` value in my `setattr(self, varname, default)` line from `typed_property`. The `default` parameter to `typed_property` is really a reference to a single object in memory... So when that assignment happens what's really happening is a reference to `default` is being assigned to my property's internal storage, right?

I can fix the issue by changing `setattr(self, varname, default)` to be `setattr(self, varname, copy.deepcopy(default)` but is that the best way to go?

Ideally, I'd like to just use a `dataclass` but unfortunately it doesn't handle all the cases we need to cover.

If someone can articulate or post a link to some info that explains what's going on here in memory with that `default` function argument it'd be helpful for my understanding. Are arguments always fixed references or is it the default argument that's created once by Python?

It would be nice to either confirm what I'm thinking or learn more about the internals of the language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that the reference to the default value is shared between `MyClass` instances, and your tests confirm as much. One important piece of information to understand why this happens is that, other than e.g. the body of an `__init__` function, a class-body only gets evaluated once; on class creation. There is no way for two or more different default-objects to exist, because the code related to it does not get executed when creating a new `MyClass` instance.

`dataclasses` solve this issue of having default values defined in the class body by having both `default` for immutable default values and `default_factory` for mutable default values. I'd suggest to just use a similar pattern for your construct, the alternative of creating copies is bound to create problems in case you actually do want to share an object between instances:

```py
def typed_property(name, default_factory=lambda: None):
    varname = "_" + name

    @property
    def prop(self):
        if not hasattr(self, varname):
            setattr(self, varname, default_factory())
        return getattr(self, varname)

    @prop.setter
    def setter(self, value):
        setattr(self, varname, value)

    return prop

class MyClass:
    data = typed_property("data", default_factory=dict)
```

By passing the `dict` function as the factory that gets called with the initial `settatr`, you get new dictionary objects for each instance. If you want to share some object `o = MySharedObject()`, just define the field as `typed_property("shared_data", lambda: o)`. Or go all the way and define both `default` and `default_factory` arguments, but it will make the `typed_property` implementation a bit more complex with checking that only either the one or the other is used and what not.

And to show that it works now:

```py
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> id(a.data)
140412230286208
>>> b = MyClass()
>>> id(b.data)
140412230275328
>>> id(a.data)
140412230286208
```

Comment: Thanks @Arne for the explanation, but here's another question... in some cases I may need the `default` argument to be something that isn't callable... for example, I may need that default dictionary to be pre-populated with some fields... such as `data = typed_property('data', default={'foo': 1}` ... 

In this case if I give it something like that then the call of `default_factory` will trigger an error when it's used.  Is there something bad with using a deepcopy there instead?

Comment: you can either pass `default_factory=lambda: {'foo': 1}`, or implement both both default and default_factory. I can add the latter to my answer, I avoided it initially because it would blow up the linecount and could lead to bugs or confusing behavior.

Comment: @TxAG98 For completeness' sake, [here](https://gist.github.com/a-recknagel/7b4b869bfba460535c85b9c4e0ef789d) is an implementation with both options, with the short rule being immutable values go into `default`, mutable values go into `default_factory` - either by passing their constructor, or by passing a populated instance with a `lambda`.